# Adding Asp .NET Core Controller dynamically when analyzing route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Summary:

Imagine we are calling the url http://localhost:5600/Student/All/
My goal is that my Asp .NET Core Web Api compiles a Student controller on the fly when that route is called and then uses that controller for answering that request.

Detailed:

I want to compile an Asp .NET Core Controller when analyzing the route. So I'm using a DynamicRouteValueTransfer to analyze the route and modify it when needed.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    //...
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SearchValueTransformer>("{controller}/{action}/{**params}");
    //...
```

In the SearchValue Transfer (inherited from DynamicRouteValueTransfer) I can analyze and rewrite the route. There I'm compiling an Controller with a Get method which returns a list of Students (with an OData - [EnableQuery] - attribute because in the end I want to provide any data for OData access).

Then I try to add this newly compiled StudentController to the Controllers to be used in that request. But that is **not** working.

I tried saving the IMvcBuilder which I get at startup at the ConfigureServices:

```
//inside ConfigureServices - MvcManager is my static class
MvcManager.Builder = services.AddMvc();

//in my static class
public static IMvcBuilder Builder { get; set; }
```

After compiling the Controller I tried to add that Assembly by calling

```
MvcManager.Builder.AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
```

The problem is that I can't go into that controller. I found some articles about dynamically adding but none is doing it while the request is already started.

Comment: Have a look at this page: [strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)

Comment: Yes true that example is already very dynamic. They generate the entity classes at runtime.
But for me that isn't enough as I really need the compiled controller.

Comment: Let's precise what I said: I want to generate the controller while the request comes in. In the link you shared there the controllers are created at startup time.

Comment: @Dennis1679: Your link helped me! The missing idea I missed there was using a middleware to add the controller instead of doing it at the startup as on the link. Thank you Dennis!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some search I finally found the optimal solution to create controllers at runtime based on the request path coming in.

Here is the solution - you have to use a middleware. In the middleware you can compile according to the request route and add it as AssemblyPart to your current assembly. Example:
The request
http://localhost:56002/Account/getdata
comes in. You can get the "/Account/getdata" in your middleware and compile an account controller with a get method with name getdata inside. The middleware compiles the controller, add it as AssemblyPart to the currently running assembly and after the middleware has finished the controller can directly be used.

First you have to add a middleware. There you can

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    //...
        app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

The middleware can look like that:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDel, ControllerGenerator generator)
    {
        RequestDel = requestDel;
        Generator = generator;
    }

    public RequestDelegate RequestDel { get; }
    public ControllerGenerator Generator { get; }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
        {
            var queryParams = context.Request.Path.Value;
            var entityName = queryParams.Split("/").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).FirstOrDefault();
            var result = Generator.AppendController(entityName);
            Console.WriteLine(result + ", " + queryParams);
        }

        await RequestDel.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

The controller generator looks like that in my case. The important thing here is the ApplicationPartManager which can be used to add the assembly (part) to the current assembly.

```
public class ControllerGenerator
{
    private readonly ApplicationPartManager _partManager;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ControllerGenerator(
        ApplicationPartManager partManager,
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _partManager = partManager;
        _hostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public bool AppendController(string className)
    {
        var generator = new WebApiGenerator();

        Assembly assembly = generator.Exists(className) ?
            generator.GetAssembly(className) : generator.CreateDll(className);

        if (assembly != null)
        {
            _partManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
            // Notify change
            MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance.HasChanged = true;
            MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance.TokenSource.Cancel();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The ActionDescriptorChangeProvider is used to inform the framework that something has changed and has to be reloaded.

```
public class MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider : IActionDescriptorChangeProvider
{
    public static MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider Instance { get; } = new MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider();

    public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; private set; }

    public bool HasChanged { get; set; }

    public IChangeToken GetChangeToken()
    {
        TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        return new CancellationChangeToken(TokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register that Action Descriptor at startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IActionDescriptorChangeProvider>(MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance);
        services.AddSingleton(MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance);
```

My code generator just creates a controller and an entity class. The controller returns a OData enabled list of entities with three properties on it. Nothing special, just here to have a working example for someone who want to try this out.

```
public class WebApiGenerator
{
    public WebApiGenerator()
    {
    }

    private static CSharpCompilation GenerateCode(string sourceCode, string className)
    {
        var codeString = SourceText.From(sourceCode);
        var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.CSharp9);

        var parsedSyntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(codeString, options);

        var references = new List<MetadataReference>
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo).Assembly.Location),
        };

        var referencedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (var referenced in referencedAssemblies)
        {
            string location = null;
            try
            {
                location = referenced.Location;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            if (location != null)
            {
                references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(location));
            }
        }

        string outputDll = className + ".dll";
        return CSharpCompilation.Create(outputDll,
            new[] { parsedSyntaxTree },
            references: references,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,
                assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default));
    }

    public bool Exists(string className)
    {
        string outputDll = className + ".dll";
        return File.Exists(outputDll);
    }

    public Assembly GetAssembly(string className)
    {
        string outputDll = className + ".dll";
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(outputDll);
    }

    public Assembly CreateDll(string className)
    {
        className = className.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

        string outputDll = className + ".dll";
        if (File.Exists(outputDll)) return Assembly.LoadFrom(outputDll);

        var code = new StringBuilder()
            .AppendLine("using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;")
            .AppendLine("using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;")
            .AppendLine("using System;")
            .AppendLine("using System.Collections.Generic;")
            .AppendLine("using System.Linq;")
            .AppendLine("using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;")
            .AppendLine("")
            .AppendLine("namespace ControllerLibrary")
            .AppendLine("{")
            .AppendLine($"public class {className}")
            .AppendLine("{")
            .AppendLine("   public string FirstProperty { get; set; }")
            .AppendLine("   public string SecondProperty { get; set; }")
            .AppendLine("   public int IntValue { get; set; }")
            .AppendLine("}")
            .AppendLine($"[ApiController]")
            .AppendLine($"[Route(\"[controller]\")]")
            .AppendLine($"public class {className}Controller : ControllerBase")
            .AppendLine(" {")
            .AppendLine("  [HttpGet(\"GetData\")]")
            .AppendLine("  [EnableQuery]")
            .AppendLine($"  public IList<{className}> Get()")
            .AppendLine("  {")
            .AppendLine($"  var list = new List<{className}>();");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            code.AppendLine($"list.Add(new {className} {{ FirstProperty = \"First prop of {className}\", SecondProperty = \"asd\", IntValue = {i} }});");
        }
        code
            .AppendLine("  return list;")
            .AppendLine("  }")
            .AppendLine(" }")
            .AppendLine("}");

        File.WriteAllText("code.txt", code.ToString());

        var result = GenerateCode(code.ToString(), className).Emit(outputDll);
        //CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code.ToString());
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Compilation done with error.");
            var failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic => diagnostic.IsWarningAsError || diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

            foreach (var diagnostic in failures)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Build Succeeded");
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(outputDll);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gerry, I'm trying to do something similar to what you are showing here. Unfortunately on the first request, the controller is compiled and added to the selfhosted server but the request failed (404). The request succeed only on the second call. Did you experience the same problem? Seems adding the controller on the fly using Middleware may be too late in the request flow to properly succeed on first call. Also i'm looking for a way to update on the fly an existing controller that has been loaded already (recompile the dll and reload). Any idea?

Comment: I had created following request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477394/how-to-dynamically-add-a-controller-in-a-asp-net-core-6-mvc-application
but no luck so far. Any help, insights will be greatly appreciated!. Thanks